# I don't know what is wrong with this code

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I don't know what is wrong with this code, but it just jumps to the `else` part. Can you please help me out?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TB_VH_HW where UserName='" + Txtusername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", con);
con.Open();

int i = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (i == 1)
    Server.Transfer("userlogin.aspx");
else
    Label1.Text = "login faileed";
```

The table columns are `UserName` and `Password` only

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Additionally passwords should NOT be stored in clear text. They should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
  select count(*) from ..
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. If your first column is not 1 you will always go to "else". And yes the above comments about the sql injection and storing the password apply.